# how to fix a static generic method that recives an array of objects

Tags: java, generics, static, hashmap

I have an issue regarding a static function that I wrote that receives a generic Object array that contains a key and a value. When it finds keys with the same value it adds the values for that key; however, I'm having issues at making the function static. The code is as following:

```
public static<K,V extends Number> void mapSumOfValues(/*Map<K,V> h,*/ DataObject<K, V> []dataarray) {
    Map<K,V> h = new HashMap<>();
    Integer sum = 0;
    for(DataObject<K,V> d: dataarray) {
        h.merge(d.getKey(), d.getValue().intValue(), Integer:: sum);
    }
```

I get the error:

> The method merge(K, V, BiFunction) in
>   the type Map is not applicable for the arguments (K, int,
>   Integer::sum)

Comment: Hi, use V extends Integer or h.merge(d.getKey(),new Integer(d.getValue().intValue()),  Integer:: sum);

Answer (score 0):

Your merge function only works for `Integer`, so you need a `Map<K, Integer>`.

```
Map<K, Integer> h = new HashMap<>();
for (DataObject<K, V> d : dataarray) {
    h.merge(d.getKey(), d.getValue().intValue(), Integer::sum);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that Integer::sum would be automatically boxed into a ```BiFunction<Integer, Integer>```? Not saying that it won't but I think it could be problematic.

Comment: I checked and in fact it does! So don't mind my comment above.